# Why DROP INDEX IF EXISTS generates a MySQL note

Tags: indexing, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and I have a sql file which looks like this:

```
create table table1(
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     name varchar(50))
);
drop index if exists my_index on table1;
create fulltext index my_index on table1(name);
```

When i run this file with `source file.sql` it generates this warning:

```
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                  |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1091 | Can't DROP 'my_index'; check that column/key exists                      |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to take this warning away?

Comment: `nome` !== `name`

Comment: sorry, missclick @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well, it works without error in this *db<>fiddle test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a801e4edd8e934861a67ad6d74ac680f)*.  So I guess you just don't want the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have founded here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-index/

> If the IF EXISTS clause is used, then MariaDB will return a warning
>   instead of an error if the index does not exist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so in other words, is nothing to care about

Comment: Well, yes, but I am checking to see how to resolve this: "Is there a way to take this warning away?" There is a table : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-index_statistics-table/ that you can query and check if the index exists. And then if it exists drop it and if not...but I can not run it on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4 to test that... sorry. Maybe this comment will also be of some help...